# UIView.animation of transformation property doesn't work on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uiviewanimation

I have created a project with a view controller, which is set to be the initial one. There is another view controller which is a subclass of UITableViewController which is presenting a subclass of UITableViewCell which has a single outlet to an image view.

A button on the initial view controller presents the table view controller which in the 'willDisplayCell' method is setting an animation on the transformation property of the image outlet of a cell. It doesn't work on when the tableview is presented as a card (modalPresentationStyle == .automatic) and it works when modalPresentationStyle == .fullScreen

Is this a UIKit bug? My configuration is Xcode 12.4 (iOS 14.4)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cel") as? CustomCell {
        fatalError()
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse]) {
        cell.customImage.transform = .init(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
    }
}

class CustomCell {
    @IBOutlet private(set) var customImage: UIImageView!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't `dequeue` a new cell -- the function is already giving you a reference to the cell with this part of the signature:

```
willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell
```

However, you have run into a bit of quirk. I'm not sure, but it *seems* that when using `.automatic` for the presentation style, the `UIView.animate(...)` call is acting on the ***presenting*** controller, instead of the ***presented*** controller. Possibly because UIKit generates the table at a different point in time.

One way to get your animation to work would be to make sure that call happens *after* the view hierarchy is fully completed.

Try it like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let c = cell as? CustomCell {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse]) {
                c.customImage.transform = .init(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Quick testing shows this works if the table view:

- is the root view controller, or
- is pushed onto a navigation stack, or
- is presented with `.automatic`, or
- is presented with `.fullScreen`

---

**Edit** - *a little more discussion...*

There are differences between presenting with `.automatic` and `.fullScreen`.

In particular, with `.automatic`, when you dismiss the presented view controller `viewDidAppear()` in the **presenting** controller does ***NOT*** get called.

So, the overall view / controller hierarchy is not what we may be expecting, and (clearly) affects what we're trying to do here.

It's worth noting, also... if we don't delay the `UIView.animate(...)` call, the `customImage` in each cell shows up *transformed to `1.2` scale*!

So, what appears to be happening is... somewhere as UIKit configures, renders and displays the modal view controller, this line gets executed:

```
c.customImage.transform = .init(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
```

and then the `[.repeat, .autoreverse]` animation is scaling the image view from `1.2` to `1.2` and back again (instead of from `1.0` to `1.2`)... so we don't see any visual change.

Comment: "... table at a different point in time." Can you develop this part of your answer?

Comment: @BlazejSLEBODA - see the **Edit** in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't dequeue another cell here - you're already given the cell in the method signature. Dequeuing is for when you want to get a cell object from the reuse pool to return in `tableView(_: cellForRow at:)`.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse]) {
        (cell as? CustomCell)?.customImage.transform = .init(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right but this is not a source of the problem and not doing it is not a solution